# CSS Adjacent Sibling Selector

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the next `li` element to have a top border after a `ul`.

Just need Link 5 to have a border above and I'm not sure why it's not working.

Trying to use Adjacent sibling selectors

The adjacent sibling selector selects all elements that are the adjacent siblings of a specified element.
Sibling elements must have the same parent element, and "adjacent" means "immediately following".

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/daduber/pen/ZKXzjE)

```css
.productCatUl {
 font-size: 14px;
 list-style: none;
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 padding-left: 4px;
 padding-right: 4px;
}
.productCatUlSub {
 list-style: none;
 padding-left: 12px;
}
.productCatUl a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #999999;
 display: block;
}
.productCatUl a:hover {
 color: #1957a7;
 padding-left: 3px;
}
.productCatUl > li:first-child {
 border-top: 1px #999999 solid;
}
.productCatUl> li >a {
 border-bottom: 1px #999999 solid;
 padding-top: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.productCatUlSub li a {
 border-bottom: 0;
}
.productCatUl li + .productCatUl li {
 border-top: 1px #999999 solid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="productCatUl">
   <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <ul class="productCatUlSub">
    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 5</a></li>
  </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `border-top` to the `li`'s and to the `.productCatUlSub`'s, and a border-bottom to the outer menu `.productCatUl`

```css
.productCatUl {
 font-size: 14px;
 list-style: none;
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 padding-left: 4px;
 padding-right: 4px;
}
.productCatUlSub {
 list-style: none;
 padding-left: 12px;
}
.productCatUl a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #999999;
 display: block;
}
.productCatUl a:hover {
 color: #1957a7;
 padding-left: 3px;
}
.productCatUl > li, .productCatUlSub {
 border-top: 1px #999999 solid;
}
.productCatUl {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
.productCatUl> li >a {
 padding-top: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.productCatUlSub li a {
 border-bottom: 0;
}
.productCatUl li + .productCatUl li {
 border-top: 1px #999999 solid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="productCatUl">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <ul class="productCatUlSub">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
</ul>
```